# Props don't seem to be passed along in a React app

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I recently started working with React so forgive me if my question is very basic. Props in a component don't seem to be passed along.
Below is my code.

**dogDetails component**

```
import React from 'react';

const DogDetails = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h4>{'Dog details of '+ props.breed}</h4>
        </div>
    )
};
export default DogDetails;
```

In Dog component I have a method that returns a DogDetails component as shown below.

```
import React , {Component} from 'react'
import Dog from './Dog/Dog';
import classes from './Dogs.css';
import  Aux from '../../hoc/Auxillary/Auxillary';
import {Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import DogDetails from './Dog/DogDetails/DogDetails';
class Dogs extends Component {
    state = {
        loadedDogs: []
    };
    componentDidMount () {
        this.setState({
            loadedDogs:[]
        })
    }

    dogDetailsHandler = (dog) =>{
        console.log(dog.breed);
        return <DogDetails breed={dog.breed}/>;
    };

    render() {
        const loadDogs = this.state.loadedDogs.map(dog => {
            return <Dog
                url={dog.images[0].image1}
                alt={dog.id}
                breed={dog.breed}
                temperament={dog.temperament}
                id={dog.id}
                key={dog.id}
                clicked ={() => this.dogDetailsHandler(dog)}>
            </Dog>

        });
        return (
            <Aux>
                {loadDogs}
            </Aux>
        )
    }
}
export default Dogs;
```

I have omitted the content of the loadedDogs array to reduce the code size.
Below is the Dog component

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './Dog.css';
import {Link, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
const dog = (props) => {
    return(
        <div className={classes.Dog}>
            <div>
                <img src={props.url} alt ={props.id}/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4>{'Breed: ' + props.breed}</h4>
                <h5>{'Temperament: ' + props.temperament}</h5>
                <p>
                    <Link to = '#'>... Read more ...</Link>
                </p>
                <Link to={'/shop/'+ props.id}>
                <button onClick={props.clicked}>Order</button>
                </Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};
export default dog;
```

I'm routing the DogDetails in the MainContent component like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './MainContent.css';
import Dogs from './Dogs/Dogs';
import Contact from '../Contact/Contact';
import {Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import DogDetails from './Dogs/Dog/DogDetails/DogDetails';
const main = () =>{
    return (
        <div className={classes.MainContent}>
            <Route path='/' exact component = {Dogs}/>
            <Route path='/shop' exact component = {Dogs}/>
            <Route path={'/shop/:id'} exact component={DogDetails}/>
            <Route path='/contact' exact component ={Contact}/>
        </div>
    )
};
export default main;
```

Here is a sample code sandbox to demonstrate what I'm trying to work on. I want the DogDetails component to show up when the Order button is clicked.

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/7zjvzrzlwj)

The dogDetails component `<h4>` tag is returning undefined. Please help me find where I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: could you show dogDetailsHandler is being used?

Comment: what if you rename `dogDetails` to `DogDetails ` ?

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk

Comment: Do you have any async request in your parent ?

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk I renamed it and I was sure it might be the reason but unfortunately it didn't work. It still shows undefined.

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif No I don't have any async requests

Comment: where do you call dogDetailsHandler? can you show that part of the code as well?

Comment: @Geoman I call dogDetailsHandler when a button is clicked. Check the code. `  render() {
        const loadDogs = this.state.loadedDogs.map(dog => {
            return <Dog
                url={dog.images[0].image1}
                alt={dog.id}
                breed={dog.breed}
                temperament={dog.temperament}
                id={dog.id}
                key={dog.id}
                clicked ={() => this.dogDetailsHandler(dog)}>
            </Dog>

        });
        return (
            <Aux>
                {loadDogs}
            </Aux>
        )
    }`

Comment: so loadDogs get passed to Aux component? how do you pass it to dogDetails? please add your question, its really hard to read code when its not formatted, also show us whole flow how your data is created and then passed down to other components. it gets lost somewhere.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to route your button-click to a Component? using react-router?

Answer (score 0):

Capitalize both `dogDetails` and `dogDetailsHandler`

> **User-Defined Components Must Be Capitalized**
>   [from react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/j25kn3l8jv)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using routing, I'm not sure why you have a button handler inside of a routed `<Link />`. Clicking on this element will route you to `/shop/:id`, and the return method of `dogDetailsHandler` will do nothing.

I have emulated your code and added a `<Route />` I'm not sure if this is what you are after, but when I click "Order", I'll get routed to `/shop/:id` with the `DogDetails` component being rendered as it should.

Add this routing component after your `<Link />` component and see if this is the behavior you are after.

```
<Route path="/shop/:id" render={
    () => <DogDetails {...props} />
} />
```

Comment: I'm actually routing like that in the MainContent component to render the contents of DogDetails there. I have edited the post to show where I add the Route.